# How to access public/custom indicators in code when backtesting

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine Script. I'm writing backtest code for different strategies. I would like to be able to read from a custom or public indicator in my code. Can someone let me know how I can do this?

I know that I can read from built-in indicators such as EMA:

```
ema20 = ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ema(close, 50)
```

How do I do the same for an indicator in the TradingView public library or ones that I've created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just click this icon `{}` beside the indicator name. Some publishers don't share their source code, some do.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to read the source code. What I mean is how can I call public or custom indicator functions from my backtesting code so I can use them in backtesting as a signal?

Comment: Calling from a separate script is not possible.  You need to import them manually.